# Получить enum с помощью ввода строки

Tags: swift, enum

Не совсем понимаю какой смысл от enum. В интернете нахожу только примеры, где элемент перечисления вызывают с помощью подобной конструкции:

```
enum Titles: Int {
    case Private, Super, Vip, Top
}

var titles = Titles.Top // Вот так

switch titles {
case .Private:
    print("Получен статус Private")
case .Super:
    print("Получен статус Super")
case .Vip:
    print("Получен статус Vip")
case .Top:
    print("Получен статус Top")
}
```

Но, какой от этого вообще смысл, если каждый раз нужно объявлять переменную **var titles** и указывать ей **Titles.Top**? 
Вот например: Я получаю от пользователя какой-то ввод, например строку «Private», и хочу чтобы он получил ответ «Получен статус Private». Как я это могу сделать? Мне нужно городить кучу if-else проверяя ввод? Какой тогда вообще смысл от перечислений? В чем их удобство?

Comment: Вы немного не понимаете смысл перечислений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать можно реализовать так

```
enum Titles: Int {
    case Private, Super, Vip, Top
    case none


    var message: String {
        switch self {
        case .Private:
            return "Получен статус Private"
        case .Super:
            return "Получен статус Super"
        case .Vip:
            return "Получен статус Vip"
        case .Top:
            return "Получен статус Top"
        case .none:
            return "Получен неопределенный статус"
        }
    }

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self = Titles(rawValue: value) ?? .none
    }

    init(_ value: String) {

        switch value.lowercased() {
        case "private":
            self = .Private
        case "super":
            self = .Super
        case "vip":
            self = .Vip
        case "top":
            self = .Top
        default:
            self = .none
        }
    }
}


// Для примера считатем что у нас пользователь ввел статус и пробуем инициализировать наш enum

func printMessage(for userInput: Int) {
    print(Titles(userInput).message)
}

func printMessage(for userInput: String) {
    print(Titles(userInput).message)
}

printMessage(for: 2) //Получен статус Vip
printMessage(for: 197834) //Получен неопределенный статус

printMessage(for: "TOP") //Получен статус Top
printMessage(for: "sdfdsg  ") //Получен неопределенный статус
```